# macOS - MySQLWorkbench "cannot start SSH tunnel manager" only when opened via command line

Tags: terminal, osx, mysql

I'm trying to get two instances of MySQLWorkbench running simultaneously but I'm running into this issue. If I navigate to my applications and double click the application everything works fine and I can connect to my remote databases, but if I try:

```
open /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app
```

then I get the error "cannot start SSH tunnel manager" when trying to connect to any remote databases. I've tried running with `sudo` and various combinations of `Fna` but still nothing. The `man` pages for `open` even say:

> The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the file's icon.

Comment: Can you connect to remote databases when only the `open` MySQLWorkbench is running? I’m guessing that your first session is using sockets that the second session is also trying to use. Resulting in the second SSH Tunnel Manager being unable to start.

Comment: No, even if I have just a single session open it still cannot connect when opened via the `open` command

Comment: Interesting. When the process is running from an icon click, what user owns it? Is it the same user as when you use the `open` command?

Comment: not sure, is there any easy way to check this?